# Sobolev space and partial derivative. Showing that $D_j:H^{s}\to H^{s-1}$.

Tags: sobolev-spaces

[image]

To show that $D_j u\in H^{s-1}$ I need to see that $\langle \xi \rangle^{s-1}D_j u\in L^2$ when $\langle \xi \rangle^{s}u\in L^2$

Why $D_ju\in H^{s-1}$?

Comment: Since the notation $D_j$ is unfamiliar to me (although I can guess what it is but I could easily be wrong) could you give me a source for your problem? You seem to have used a textbook : which one?

Comment: Taylor partial differential equations, volume I.

D_j is the j-partial derivative.

Comment: Great, I thought so. I'll look through the material and get back to you.

Comment: This is in the page 316

Comment: Got it, I found the source. I'm looking at the kind of derivative exchange that's been performed on page 205 with the $D^{\alpha},D_j$ etc. and I'm thinking that you can perform integration by parts on $\langle \xi\rangle^{s-1} D_ju$, transposing the $D_j$ will be helpful.

Comment: Thinking more about it, that IS the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything's done in terms of the Fourier transform, so it's no surprise that this should be too. Just remember that the derivative $D_j$ on the Fourier transform side is multiplication by $\xi_j$ so that
$$
|\xi_j|\langle \xi\rangle^{s-1}|\hat{u}| \leq \langle \xi \rangle^s|\hat{u}|,
$$
where we used that $|\xi_j|\leq \langle \xi\rangle$. The $L^2$ norm of the left hand side is $\| D_ju\|_{H^{s-1}}$, while the right hand side's is $\| u\|_{H^s}$.